# Azure SQL Database Elastic Pools - TSQL to get current Elastic Pool

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I would like to be able to fetch the name of the elastic pool that the current database belongs to using TSQL  but the only DMV I can find with a column containing elastic is sys.elastic_pool_resource_stats
& I don't see any reference to databases there. I also checked sys.databases to see if an extra column got sneaked on there but nothing I could recognise.

Ideally this should work like @@servername or db_name()
(when on earth will they get around to creating server_name() or @@dbname so that we can code consistently ?)

Does anyone know a suitable command ?

(btw no tag for "elastic pools")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about [this](https://vijredblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/19/tsql-to-find-databases-corresponding-elastic-pool-names-and-db-edition-azure/)?

```
-- TSQL to find Databases, corresponding elastic pool names and DB edition
 
SELECT
       @@SERVERNAME as [ServerName],
       dso.elastic_pool_name,
       d.name as DatabaseName,
       dso.edition
FROM
       sys.databases d inner join sys.database_service_objectives dso on d.database_id = dso.database_id
WHERE d.Name <> 'master'
ORDER BY
       d.name, dso.elastic_pool_name
```

Comment: That works - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it, though the solution is rather limited, because this DMV is only available in the master database and you can't actually refer to it from within a user database.

```
select d.name,  o.* 
from sys.database_service_objectives o
join sys.databases d on
  o.database_id = d.database_id
```